# Read and Write in Word file using Visual studio 2005

Tags: file, ms-word, doc

How to read and write a MS word file in VB.net or C# .net

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Office automation for this.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76d2d007(VS.80).aspx) article as a starting point. Follow the links on that page for more information.

You may also want to purchase (any of) these books:

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-NET-Development-Office-Progmng/dp/0735621322/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1231226233&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621322)

[http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Studio-Tools-Office-Development/dp/0321334884/ref=pd_sim_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334884)

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Applications-Microsoft-Office-Outlook/dp/0735622493/ref=pd_sim_b_5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735622493)